# element read in ArrayList

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, foreach

I have a method where I loop through the ArryList and search whether the element if found. The problem is that it instead of each element from ArryList it inputs the whole ArrayList. Is there's smth wrong with adding the text from file as valueOf?

```
 public ArrayList<String> findWord(String input) {
    ArrayList<String> search = new ArrayList<>();
    search.add(String.valueOf(workfiles("D:\\Project\\synonyms.txt")));
     String[] inputs = input.split("  ");//Considering delimiter is double space("  ") in user input
     for (String inputEntry : inputs) //Giving each word as input at a time and search for it in word String
    {
        for (String element: search) {  // PROBLEM IS HERE
            System.out.println(element);
                if (element.startsWith(inputEntry) && element.contains("=")) {
                    String[] parts = element.split("=");
                    searchWord.add(parts[1]);
                    System.out.println(searchWord);
                }

        }
           }
        return null;  // RETURNS THE SYNONIM OF THE WORD
    }
```

The Workfiles method is in abstract class

```
public abstract class WorkWithFiles {
public ArrayList<String> workfiles(String path){
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
        Scanner inputreader = new Scanner(fileInputStream);
        ArrayList<String> sins = new ArrayList();
        while (inputreader.hasNextLine()) {
            String l = inputreader.nextLine();
            sins.add(l);   // REWRITES DATA FROM FILE TO ARRATLIST
        }
        inputreader.close();
        return sins;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("File not found");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

UPD
What I got printing each element:
[image]

Comment: `search.add(String.valueOf(workfiles("D:\\Project\\synonyms.txt")));` looks dubious, because that adds the string representation of the list as a single string, rather than the contents of the list as separate strings. Do you really mean `search.addAll(workfiles("..."));`?

Comment: Is the problem that there is only one `element` string in the `search` list, and that is a `[list,of,lines,from,workfile]`?

Comment: @AndyTurner I thought about it too. Actually I wanted just to rewrite the data I got from workfiles method to the usual ArrayList<String> and than do what I do

Comment: @cricket_007just posted a screen of a log.
The problem actually that nothing is writen to searchWord Array, but I guess smth is wrong with looping thought each element